# notebook-like Vim and IPython shell

Tags: vim, jupyter-notebook

### Use case

I want to download an ipython notebook as a .py file, as I dislike working within the jupyter notebook environment. But I want to use Vim and an ipython shell to simulate the use/functionality of jupyter notebooks from within vim, specifically with regards to individual cell/block execution.

In details, this is what I want to do:

1. Convert jupyter notebook to .py file
2. Edit .py file in vim
3. Execute current cell/block that I am editing in Vim in an IPython shell, to see results.
4. Return to edit .py file

   - loop 2-4 until done, possibly convert back to ipynb.

My current setup has Vim running with split windows. The first window is displaying the .py file for edit and the second is running a vim terminal window `:term` and running an IPython shell below the first window.

This is what a .py file that was converted from an ipython notebook looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:
import numpy as np
# In[2]:
x = 3
# In[3]:
y = 4
z = 5
```

I want to create one vim keybinding that detects which cell block I am currently editing in vim in the .py file, highlights it, copies it to clipboard, and then switches windows to the IPython shell, and, if possible, pastes it, executes it, and return to the vim .py file editor window.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
nnoremap <C-y> /# In\[.*\]: <CR> j <C-v> n k "+y
```

Note: I do NOT want to use vim keybindings from within jupyter notebook. I want to enable jupyter like behavior and use from within vim itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many spaces in the mapping. Remember: `vim` runs a mapping literally, a space means a space, not a separator between commands. This works for me:

```
:nnoremap <C-y> /# In\[.*\]:<CR>jVnk"+y
```

*Upd*. To search to the end of the file use pattern [`\%$`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C%$). So you can search for "either `# In\[.*\]:` or eof":

```
\(# In\[.*\]:\|\%$\)
```

Parentheses are used to group expressions; `\|` to separate or-branches.

Comment: Thanks! Also, is it possible to paste into IPython shell that is ran through vim's :term command as a window below the .py file, then run it and return back to the editor? Any of this possible?

Comment: No idea, never used IPython or vim's `:term`. When I need a terminal I run a terminal emulator (I use `rxvt-unicode`). When I need a Python command line I run pure Python with heavily configured `PYTHONSTARTUP`. `vim` for me is just a text editor, I don't use it as IDE.

Comment: Got it. Also, I noticed that this doesn't work for the last block as there is no In[...] at the end of the file. Is there a way to fix that? If not it would be pretty straightforward to just add the line at the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks. I modified your macro to this and it works now:                       
               ```:nnoremap <C-y> /\(# In\[.*\]:\)\\|\(\%$\)<CR>NjVnk"+ynj:noh<CR>``` . Please modify your original answer so I can mark it as answered.

Comment: I'm not sure why when normally searching in the vim editor using "/" I just need one "\" before the pipe "|" character, but in .vimrc i had to use two for the macro to work.

Comment: I fixed a highlighting issue when at last block, macro should be  ```:nnoremap <C-y> /\(# In\[.*\]:\)\\|\(\%$\)<CR>NjVnk"+yn:noh<CR>j```

Comment: You need a backslash before the pipe because it's [the syntax of regular expressions](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#search-pattern) in vim: *A pattern is one or more branches, separated by "__\|__".*

Comment: Why did the macro work only when there were two backslashes before the pipe?